# how to get xpath for an element using text() function where text have Apostrophe

Tags: java, xpath, selenium-webdriver, appium

In my application, I am trying to get the xpath of one of element with the static text as ***We're here 24/7***
As expected the below traditional way dosen't work as Apostrophe within text treated as end of statement.
[text()='We're here 24/7']

As of now, I have used Contains function as work around. 
Let me know if there is any way to use text function.

Comment: try using concatenation such as "//*[text()='We"+"'"+"re here 24/7']"

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes:

```
[text()="We're here 24/7"]
```

If the XPath expression is already in double quotes in Java code, you need to backslash them.